# Localhost 404 when using ASP.NET Core routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-routing

Whenever I add any kind of Route to my Controllers, every request just ends with 404. Application works normal when there's no [Route] but it breaks when I add it. The project which I downloaded worked before, works fine on different machines and my old projects don't work anymore, so probably something got updated/I broke something.

`ValuesController:`

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ValuesService _valuesService;

    public ValuesController()
    {
        _valuesService = new ValuesService(); 
    }

    [HttpGet]
    IActionResult ReturnValues()
    {
        return Ok(_valuesService.ReturnValues());
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IStudentResearchGroupData, StudentResearchGroupData>();
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                                   JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
                                   JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.Authority = "http://localhost:59418";
        o.Audience = "researchgroups";
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Result:
404 messege:
[image: 404 messege]

Comment: What is your action method called? Does URL `http://localhost:57279:/api/values/index` work for example?

Comment: Ive added all code and tried the URL, didnt work.

Comment: Well your action method isn't called `Index`, try `http://localhost:57279:/api/values/returnvalues` instead.

Comment: HttpGet default to the root of the controller so the path for provided code would be `http://localhost:57279:/api/values` given the attribute routes used. Also the action needs to be public

Comment: Oh yes, action isn't public - good spot @Nkosi

Comment: @Nkosi it was the public issue with this one, thank you.
No idea why the others didnt work though, I propably typed my routes wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HttpGet` defaults to the root of the controller when not route template is given.

that would mean that the path for the provided code would be

```
http://localhost:57279:/api/values
```

given the attribute routes used.

Also the action needs to be `public` for it to be visible externally as an endpoint.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller {
    private readonly ValuesService _valuesService;

    public ValuesController() {
        _valuesService = new ValuesService(); 
    }

    //GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ReturnValues() {
        return Ok(_valuesService.ReturnValues());
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)